# Should I keep using object instead of class? Some problems with JSDocs

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I have some problems with JSDoc when I'm trying to generate the page. And I think the problem is the structure of my code.

I have multiple objects in my script like this:
*(yes, comments are in French. The generated docs will be used in only one company)*

```
/**
 * `Page` contient les méthodes de la page en général _(chargement, évènements du `<header>` et du `<footer>`, ...)_.
 * @version 1.0
 * @type {object}
 * @namespace Page
 */
var Page = {
    /**
     * Récupère les éléments du DOM utilisés par `Page` pour les évènements et le chargement.
     * @memberof Page
     * @function init
     * @return {void}
     * @example
     * Page.init();
     */
    init: function() {...},
    /**
     * Charge les modules de la page _(DataTables, vis-network)_.
     * @memberof Page
     * @function loadModules
     * @return {void}
     * @example
     * Page.init();
     */
    loadModules: function() {...},
    /**
     * Exécute quelques lignes de code juste avant le déchargement de la page.
     * **Attention, cette méthode ne doit pas être appellée.** Elle est automatiquement
     * appellée au déchargement de la page.
     * @memberof Page
     * @function beforeUnload
     * @return {void}
     */
    beforeUnload: function() {...},
    /**
     * Ajoute des évènements sur les éléments du DOM de la page.
     * @memberof Page
     * @function events
     * @return {void}
     * @example
     * Page.events();
     */
    events: function() {...},
    /**
     * Gère le chargement de la page et des différents modules.
     * @memberof Page
     * @type {object}
     * @namespace Page.loading
     */
    /**
     * Cet objet contient les méthodes associées aux éléments du `<header>`.
     * @memberof Page
     * @type {object}
     * @namespace Page.header
     */
    header: {
        /**
         * @memberof Page.header
         * @property {jQuery} navLinks Liens de navigations du `<header>`.
         */
        navLinks: undefined,
        /**
         * Récupère les éléments du `<header>`.
         * @memberof Page.header
         * @function init
         * @param {jQuery} navLinks Éléments du `<header>` ({@link Page.footer.topOfPage}).
         * @return {void}
         * @example
         * Page.header.init();
         */
        init: function(navLinks) {...},
        /**
         * Change le lien sélectionné **uniquement visuellement** _(un lien sélectionné possède un aspect différent)_.
         * @memberof Page.header
         * @function selectLink
         * @param {jQuery} navLink Élément _(`<header> > <a>`)_ que l'ont veux afficher comme "sélectionné". 
         * @return {void}
         * @example
         * Page.header.selectLink(Page.header.navLinks.eq(1));
         */
        selectLink: function(navLink) {...},
        /**
         * Ajoute les évènements du `<header>`.
         * @memberof Page.header
         * @function events
         * @return {void}
         * @example
         * Page.header.events();
         */
        events: function() {...}
    },
    ...
}
```

Each object have its properties and functions. Some properties are an object itself. The problem is that the generated page looks like this:

```
# Nav

1. Page
   a. init
   b. loadModules
   c. beforeUnload
   d. events
2. Header
   a. navLinks
   b. init
   c. selectLink
   d. events
...
```

We can see that `header` is outside of `Page` in the generated documentation and I wanted its to be inside because I have 7 other objects like this and the documentation became hard to use.

Is my problem caused by the JSDoc comments or should I use something else than objects (such as a class)? I used object because the script became easier to read and I can access to every functions ans properties at any time.

I hope I have made myself quite clear (and that I didn't make too many mistakes).
Have a nice day.

Comment: the way your object is, it's not outside of page, I'd recomment you to read the article [You don't know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS)
And it is one way of managing code, if your problem is that you have difficulty reading the code, you can refactor your code and create reusable components

Comment: I know that `header` is **inside** `Page`, and it's exactly what I wanted to do. But, on the generated documentation, `header` have its own section **outside** `Page`, and I don't want this.